# How to grey out the font as well as the checkbox

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I would like to grey out the text within my filter section of a calendar app I am building but only seem to be able to code this onto the checkbox itself.

I have already tried passing this through my SCSS containers and labels with the ~ syntax to pass done from parent to child selectors. Cannot seem to find a way to solve this without breaking DRY principles. I have managed to get this to work on the checkbox but not the font within the same container.

**Checkbox/index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import './index.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

/*
based off the fake checkbox styles from here
should still be screen-reader/keyboard accessible
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp
*/
class Checkbox extends React.Component {
render() {
    const { name, label, value, checked, onChange, handleClose, dataObject, ...rest } = this.props
    return (
        <div {...rest}>
            <label  className="checkbox-container">
                <span className="checkbox-label">{label}</span>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={checked}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={onChange} />
                <span className="checkmark"></span>
                {this.props.handleClose && <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className='checkbox-icon' size="1x" icon={['fal', 'times']} />}
            </label>

        </div>
      )
    }
handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.handleClose(this.props.dataObject) 
 }
}

Checkbox.propTypes = {
handleClose: PropTypes.func, // optional
onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
value: PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.string,
  PropTypes.number
]).isRequired,
dataObject: PropTypes.object, // optional -> used for the 'x'   button 
checked: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
}

export default Checkbox
```

**CalendersFiltersSection/index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import './index.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Checkbox from '../../../Checkbox'
import { defaultCalendarFilters} from '../../../../../constants'

class CalendarFiltersSection extends React.Component {
render() {
    const { filters } = this.props
    // let orderedFilters  = Object.values(filters)
    // orderedFilters.sort((a,b) => {
    //  return a.displayOrder - b.displayOrder
    // })

    return (
        <section className="calendar-filters-section">
            <div className='title'>{this.props.title}</div>
            {   Object.values(filters).map(filter => {
                    let className = defaultCalendarFilters[filter.id].label.toLowerCase()

                    return <Checkbox className={`checkbox-event-type-${className}`} key={filter.id} label={filter.label} name={filter.id} checked={filter.checked} value={filter.id} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
                })
            }

        </section>
    )

  }
}

CalendarFiltersSection.propTypes = {
handleInputChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
filters: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default CalendarFiltersSection
```

**Checkbox/index.css**

```
.checkbox-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}    

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.checkbox-container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-color: #525259;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
/*.checkbox-container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
*/
/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
/*.checkbox-container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}*/

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.checkbox-container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.checkbox-container .checkmark:after {
  left: 7px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 7px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-sizing: initial;
  color: var(--secondary-font-color);
}

.checkbox-event-type-trainings .checkbox-container input:checked ~     .checkmark {
   background-color: var(--event-type-trainings-color);
}

.checkbox-event-type-medizinisch .checkbox-container input:checked     ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: var(--event-type-medizinisch-color);
}
.checkbox-event-type-spiele .checkbox-container input:checked ~  .checkmark {
  background-color: var(--event-type-spiele-color);
}
    .checkbox-event-type-tests .checkbox-container input:checked ~  .checkmark {
  background-color: var(--event-type-tests-color);
}
.checkbox-event-type-andere .checkbox-container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: var(--event-type-andere-color);
}

.checkbox-label {
  color: var(--secondary-font-color);
}

.checkbox-icon {
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 4px;
  z-index:5;
}

.checkbox-container .checkbox-icon {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.checkbox-container:hover .checkbox-icon {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

**CalendarFiltersSection/index.css**

```
.calendar-filters-section {
  align-self: flex-start;
  color: var(--secondary-font-color);
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
```

**Constants.js**

```
import { history } from './util/history'

export const API_HOST = process.env.REACT_APP_USE_STAGING_API ? 
"http://example.com" : "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
export const EVENTS_LIST_URL = `${API_HOST}/events/`
export const CALENDARS_LIST_URL = `${API_HOST}/users/calendars/`
export const USERS_LIST_URL = `${API_HOST}/users/`
export const getTeamsListUrl = (clubId) => 
`${API_HOST}/clubs/${clubId}/teams/`
export const getClubsTeamsPlayersListUrl = (clubId, teamId) => 
`${API_HOST}/clubs/${clubId}/teams/${teamId}/players/`

//TODO combine all of these into one data structure .
export const mapNameToEventTypeNumber = {
0: 'andere',
1: 'trainings',
2: 'tests',
3: 'medizinisch',
4: 'medizinisch',
5: 'medizinisch',
6: 'spiele',
8: 'medizinisch',
}

//TODO combine all of these into one data structure .
// updaet: the backend updated to use strings instead of numbers... 
export const mapMainCategoryNameToSubCategoryName = {
social: 'andere',
practice: 'trainings',
assessment: 'tests',
doctor: 'medizinisch',
physio: 'medizinisch',
operation: 'medizinisch',
match: 'spiele',
meeting: 'andere',
}


// 'event_types': ((0, 'SOCIAL'),
// (1, 'PRACTICE'),
// (2, 'ASSESSMENT'),
// (3, 'DOCTOR'),
// (4, 'PHYSIO'),
// (5, 'OPERATION'),
// (6, 'MATCH'),
// (7, 'PRIVATE'),
// (8, 'MEETING'),
// (9, 'SCHOOL/JOB'),
// (10, 'MISC')),

export const mapSpecificEventTypeCategoryToEventTypeNumber = {
0: 'Social',
1: 'Practice',
2: 'Examination',
3: 'Doctor',
4: 'Rehab',
5: 'Physio',
6: 'Match',
7: 'Injury',
8: 'Treatment',
}

export const mappingOfSpecificEventTypeToFilterCategories = {
1: 0,
3: 1,
4: 1,
5: 1,
6: 2,
2: 3,
0: 4
}

export const defaultCalendarFilters = [
{
    id: 0,
    checked: true,
    label: 'Trainings',
    eventTypeNumbers: ['practice']
    // eventTypeNumbers: ['1']
},
{
    id: 1,
    checked: true,
    label: 'Medizinisch',
    eventTypeNumbers: ['doctor','physio','operation']
    // eventTypeNumbers: ['3','4','5']
},
{
    id: 2,
    checked: true,
    label: 'Spiele',
    eventTypeNumbers: ['match']
    // eventTypeNumbers: ['6']
},
{
    id: 3,
    checked: true,
    label: 'Tests',
    eventTypeNumbers: ['assessment']
    // eventTypeNumbers: ['2']
},
{
    id: 4,
    checked: true,
    label: 'Andere',
    eventTypeNumbers: ['meeting', 'misc']
    // eventTypeNumbers: ['0']
    },
]

export const mapClubRoleNumberToSlug = {
'trainer': 0,
'athletiktrainer': 1,
'torwarttrainer': 2,
'individualtrainer': 3,
'rehabilitationtrainer': 4,
'arzt': 5,
'physiotherapeut': 6,
'videoanalyst': 7,
'athlet': 8,
'betreuer': 9,
'clubadmin': 10,
}

export const clubRolesData = {
'trainer': {
    slug: 'trainer',
    roleNum: 0,
    isStaff: true,
    isAthlete: false
},
'athletiktrainer': {
    slug: 'athletiktrainer',
    roleNum: 1,
    isStaff: true,
    isAthlete: false
},
'torwarttrainer': {
    slug: 'torwarttrainer',
    roleNum: 2,
    isStaff: true,
    isAthlete: false
},
'individualtrainer': {
    slug: 'individualtrainer',
    roleNum: 3,
    isStaff: true,
    isAthlete: false
},
'rehabilitationtrainer': {
    slug: 'rehabilitationtrainer',
    roleNum: 4,
    isStaff: true,
    isAthlete: false
},
'arzt': {
    slug: 'arzt',
    roleNum: 5,
    isStaff: true,
    isAthlete: false
},
'physiotherapeut': {
    slug: 'physiotherapeut',
    roleNum: 6,
    isStaff: true,
    isAthlete: false
},
'videoanalyst': {
    slug: 'videoanalyst',
    roleNum: 7,
    isStaff: true,
    isAthlete: false
},
'athlet': {
    slug: 'athlet',
    roleNum: 8,
    isStaff: false,
    isAthlete: true
},
'betreuer': {
    slug: 'betreuer',
    roleNum: 9,
    isStaff: true,
    isAthlete: false
},
'clubadmin': {
    slug: 'clubadmin',
    roleNum: 10,
    isStaff: true,
    isAthlete: false
},
}

export const ATHLETE_ROLES = [
'athlet'
]

export const STAFF_ROLES = [
    'arzt',
    'athletiktrainer',
    'betreuer',
    // 'clubadmin',
    'individualtrainer',
    'physiotherapeut',
    'rehabilitationtrainer',
    'torwarttrainer',
    'trainer',
    'videoanalyst',
]

export const getUserData = () =>  {
    let userData = null
    const userDataJson = localStorage.userData
    if(userDataJson) {
    userData = JSON.parse(userDataJson)
    } else {
    history.push('./login')
    return
    }
    return userData
}

export const NAVBAR_TABS = [
{
    text: 'Dein Club',
    link: '/club-member',
    active: false,
    icon: 'fa-shield'
    },
    {
    text: 'Kalender',
    link: '/calendar',
    active: false,
    icon: 'fa-calendar-alt'
    },
    {
    text: 'Library',
    link: '/library/abilities',
    active: false,
    icon: 'fa-books'
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you supply the `index.css` for the **CalendersFiltersSection** component?

Comment: Added there for you now

Comment: Also this file:

`import { defaultCalendarFilters} from '../../../../../constants'`

Comment: Also this file any other dependencies it has: `./util/history`

Comment: import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export const history = createBrowserHistory